# how to create "see more" button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add "See more"button as below image:

[image]

here is my code :

```html
<div class="main">
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="items">Friends </li>
    <li class="items">Saved </li>
    <li class="items">Pages </li>
    <li class="items">Gruop </li>
    <li class="items">Ad center</li>
    <li class="items">Campus</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want when the length of the li tag `document.querySelectorAll('.items').length > 4` then a button "See more" will appear to see the rest of the li card:

[image]

So are there any ways to do it, someone please help me. Thanks

Comment: So is your list dynamic or static?

Comment: And is it one way? Means, once the user opens it, are they can't close it back?

Comment: Check out https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp how to hide and show elements by using JS

Comment: What part of this are you stuck on?  How is your list being generated?  What have you tried in order to create this "see more" button?

Answer (score 2):

Doing it with just CSS

```css
.seeMoreCB,
.seeMoreCB + .list > .items:nth-child(n + 5) {
  display: none;
}

.seeMoreCB:checked + .list > .seeMoreLi {
  display: none;
}

.seeMoreCB:checked + .list > .items:nth-child(n + 5) {
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <input type="checkbox" id="seeMoreCB" class="seeMoreCB" />
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="items">Friends </li>
    <li class="items">Saved </li>
    <li class="items">Pages </li>
    <li class="items">Gruop </li>
    <li class="seeMoreLi"><label for="seeMoreCB">See More</label></li>
    <li class="items">Ad center</li>
    <li class="items">Campus</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using a framework like react or angular that generates your html you would probably do the filtering on the list.  However it looks like you want to use plain javascript.  You could create the entire list and use classes on the `ul` tag to hide or show the extra elements.

Here the elements that are initially hidden have the class 'extra'.  The `ul` element has the 'collapsed' class to start with.  Clicking 'more' and 'less' toggle the collapsed and expanded classes on the `ul` element.

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('ul.list');
const more = document.querySelector('ul.list > li.more');
const less = document.querySelector('ul.list > li.less');

more.addEventListener('click', event => {
  ul.classList.remove('collapsed');
  ul.classList.add('expanded');
});

less.addEventListener('click', event => {
  ul.classList.add('collapsed');
  ul.classList.remove('expanded');
});
```

```css
.list.collapsed > .extra {
  display: none;
}

.list.expanded > .more {
  display: none;
}

.list > .more {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list > .less {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list collapsed">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li class="more">&lt; more &gt;</li>
  <li class="extra">Item 5</li>
  <li class="extra">Item 6</li>
  <li class="extra">Item 7</li>
  <li class="extra">Item 8</li>
  <li class="extra">Item 9</li>
  <li class="extra less">&lt; less &gt;</li>
</ul>
```